# Multi step post wordpress

Tags: wordpress, post, multi-step

i need to create a multi step post on front end wordpress, i tried a lot but i don't reach the solution... There aren't plugin that make this and i tried to modify the code of a plugin with you can create a custom post but if i divide the fieldest in different parts with jquery the button plubish don't work... This plugin is frontier post... Now my question is: it's possible to create a multi step post on front end in wordpress? And if It possible someone could help me with code? 
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I hope following plugin will help you. [click here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/sgr-nextpage-titles/)

It splits single post in multiple pages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this plugin isn't my solution, beacause i need to allow to my users could create in front end post and i need make this in step...